# Sci fi movie where time freezes

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, hard-sci-fi

I am trying to find an old movie I saw in the 70's, and it is probably from the 60´s. Some sort of accident causes time to revert a few hours and then move very slowly again. The main character is a pilot, and he is left in the time-bubble, trying to prevent the accident from happening again.

That's all I remember. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Ecellent, this is the one. Remember the part about the truck now that you mention it, many thanks!

Comment: Well at least it doesn't sound like *The Girl, the Gold Watch, and Everything* I looked for that because I thought it was cool when I saw it as a kid but gosh I wish I hadn't... still a gold watch that stops time, that's pretty cool.

Answer (score 10):

It's an *Outer Limits* episode, [*The Premonition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Premonition_%28The_Outer_Limits%29).  It's about a test pilot who crashes, right at the point where his wife is, in her car.  They can move, but they can't move anything else.  While exploring, they find that their daughter is about to be hit by a truck that is parked without the brake on.  He has to take material from her car and his plane (because they're not frozen in time) and he jerry-rigs straps from seatbelts so as the truck moves forward, the strap will wrap around the hub and pull on the brake to stop the truck.

They find out they have to get back to their places in time for normal time to resume or they'll be trapped in "slow time" forever.

In the end, after they get back in place and are in normal time, they don't remember what's happened, other than as a premonition.

Comment: I thought about this one too when I read the question. But no, this has nothing to do with time reverting a couple of hours, and the protagonist having to prevent the same accident that caused it happening again. I don't believe it's it.